# How do you remove filter arrows from Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

A few arrows have appeared in my Excel workbook while using a Pivot Table. When there is data visible in the table the filters lay on top of the data. Is there any way you can hide these arrows?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing these was actually quite simple:

Select and delete the entire row.

Answer (score 3):

[image: go to Data tab and click on filter icon]

> Go to Data tab and click on filter icon

```
**And another way to do is by using shortcut**

 Just select the range and Press  
(1) ctrl + shift+ L in your excel.
```

Comment: Would really appreciate an explanation,like what happens when I press ctrl+shift+L is this a shortcut to any inbuilt excel functionality.Thanks